# configure remote connection for multiple instances sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've installed 2 instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 onto our local windows server.  For the purposes of testing I've turned off the firewall.  I'll get the firewall back up after I manage a successfull remote connection. The server isnt exposed anyway.

TCP\IP is turned on for both instances.  The default port is assigned to the Default instance and that one is working fine.

I've assigned 4143 to the named instance but I'm still unable to connect remotely.

I can connect remotely to the default instance just not the named instance.  What step or steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to clear out the values in the TCP dynamic ports.  I had 0 in there.

Comment: good to know that this can be one of the causes!

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the `SQL Browser service` to enable connections to named instances.

Explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Upon startup, SQL Server Browser starts and claims UDP port 1434. SQL
>   Server Browser reads the registry, identifies all instances of SQL
>   Server on the computer, and notes the ports and named pipes that they
>   use. When a server has two or more network cards, SQL Server Browser
>   returns the first enabled port it encounters for SQL Server. SQL
>   Server Browser support ipv6 and ipv4.

Comment: I had the browser started.  Good catch though I forgot to mention that in my initial notes.