# SQL Server remote connection to 2nd instance impossible

Tags: sql-server, remote, connections

After installation of another SQL Server 2014 instance to a server where a default instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 is present, I cannot remote connect remote to the new named instance.

The default 2008 R2 instance uses TCP port 1433 set for all "IP(n)" settings.

Here is what I read / checked / tried:

Following this question: [configure remote connection for multiple instances sql server 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23194/configure-remote-connection-for-multiple-instances-sql-server-2008)

I figured several settings and tried the following:

- Server Security: Mixed
- Server Connections Properties: Allow [checked]
- SQL Server Browser started
- Protocol Settings for the 2014 instance set as follows:

  - Shared Memory=Enabled,
  - Named Pipes=Disabled,
  - TCP/IP=Enabled

    - TCP IP Setting of new instance:

      - Enabled=Yes,
      - Listen All=YES,
    - TCP/IP Settings for IP(n):

      - Dynamic Ports=erased
      - TCP Port=erased
    - **IPAll** Setting:

      - Dynamic Ports = erased
      - Port=49172

I tried to remote connect using `[IP]:49172\Instance` and `HostName:49172\Instance` and `HostName\Instance` and `[IP]\Instance` without success.

I try to use SQL Server authentication, the user is available and is sysadmin and can connect local.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to restart the SQL Server Browser. Looks like my configuration was correct but has to be made before starting this service. After that I could access the 2nd Sql Server without problems, just using the name\instance.

Comment: "name\instance" There it is! I forgot, The first, default instance can simply be accesses by "localhost", but the second instance needed "localhost\instance"